# How to fine tune force touch trackpad sensitivity?

Tags: trackpad

The force touch trackpad seems great but I would like to reduce it's sensitivity.

It seems the UI allow selection of 3 modes:
Click: Light - Medium - Firm 
which both set sensitivity and the haptic feedback level.

Would it be possible to set the sensitivity in a more fine way ? Maybe by command line ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, BetterTouchTool seems to be able to modify the trackpad sensibility for 2 fingers and more clicks. It can as well change the haptic feedback strength and feeling (you can have your trackpad vibrate when you force click with two fingers). However, it's not able to change the force click with one finger but it proves that we can have a low driver access to the new macbook force touch trackpad. If somebody got any documentation on how to access these drivers, I could try to play around with that and maybe develop a little app to change the sensitivity of the pad.